# Is it possible to search specific directories inside of a directory?

Tags: vb.net, directory

I am trying to make my application unable to close until all files within specific directories have a certain prefix. My main directory has 5 sub-directories in it, but I have to make it only search 3 specific sub-directories in it? I want the app to be unable to close unless all of the files in those 3 sub-directories have the prefix...

This is the code I have so far

```
 Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

e.Cancel = True

    Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(dir)

    For Each file In directory.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

        If file.Name.Contains("prefix.") Then
            e.Cancel = False
        Else e.Cancel = True

        End If


    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to only search 3 of the 5 sub-directories, I assume their name/path is static. If so, this would work.

```
Dim directoriesToSearch() As String = {"C:\TopDirectory\SubDir1", "C:\TopDirectory\SubDir2", "C:\TopDirectory\SubDir3"}
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

For Each d In directoriesToSearch
  Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(d)

  For Each f As FileInfo In directory.EnumerateFiles()
    If f.Name.IndexOf("myPrefix") <> 0 Then
      Dim message As String = String.Format("The directory {0} does not have the valid prefix.", d)
      sb.AppendLine(message)
    End If
  Next
Next

If sb.Length > 0 Then
  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
End If
```